# UIWebView getting crashed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` which will load the documents. All the supported documents mentioned for webview it is working. But sometimes , the `UIWebView` is getting crashed whenever I move back and forth quickly. I mean I am clicking back and opening file again and again. If I do so , my app is getting crashed.

Any idea why this is happening ?? It is working cool for video,audio and txt files, but weird crashing for the Office docs and numbers,pages documents.

Please help me out !!

```
-(void) backBtnPressed
{
    [_webView stopLoading];
    if ([_webView superview])
    {      
        [_webView removeFromSuperview];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    }
}

- (void) loadFile:(NSString*)filePath
{
    NSURL*  url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest*   request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
}
```

Comment: do you set the `delegate` property of the webview to `nil` before releasing it?

Comment: @mvds - Why isn't that an answer :)

Comment: I haven't set the delegate like webview.deleget = self; and also I am releasing the webview when I am moving to the other view controller. I am opening the files from the same viewcontroller. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Your document size is to large means > 2 mb ?

Comment: Nope.Everything less than 1 MB , even < 512 KB

Comment: Please check my updated question. I am not pasting the full code, but some imp methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.Setting the UIWebView to nil and loading the request again in the WebView. But now only at most worst case the App is getting crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate property of the webview to nil in the dealloc of your controller

Comment: I haven't set the delegate like webview.deleget = self; and also I am releasing the webview when I am moving to the other view controller. I am opening the files from the same viewcontroller. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: I am using removefromsuperview and stoploading to get back

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving from one view controller to another, do the following

```
[webView stopLoading];
webView.delegate = nil;
```

Comment: I am not moving to other view controller. I am in the same view controller.

Comment: I am using removefromsuperview and stoploading

Answer (score 0):

Implement this and chk what error you are getting.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
       NSLog("Error=%s",error);
    }
```

Comment: Ya I have added that. No error log is printed. But in the debug area I can see this EXCEPTION CPMessageException: (null)

Comment: copy your `url` and paste it in your browser and check whether it is working or not ?

Comment: No. i am opening the file from the Local File path not from the net

Comment: whether that file (url) exists at iPhone simulator path ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        if([webView isLoading])
        {
            [webView stopLoading];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this here on the off chance that someone else is making the same beginner mistake:

Remember that `webView.delegate` is a **weak reference**. If you set it to something else than `self` your delegate may get destroyed if there are no other references to it, which will cause all kinds of crashes.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do the following. It works for me.

```
[webView stopLoading];
[webView release];
webView = nil;
webView.delegate = nil;
```